# Automatically folder open after save excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

below is my code for the file to be saved to specific folder. my question is how can I make the folder of the location is open automatically after save complete. I google about "aftersave event" but nothing come out .

```
Private Sub savebr_Click()

Dim saveas As String
saveas = "C:\user\file"
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show saveas

End Sub
```

Comment: you have the event `Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)` in the VB Editor->Thisworkbook

Comment: what does that mean? i found command to call out the folder is ''shell' comand but cannot set the output folder for the saved file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thisworkbook.path open every time same workbook path(i.e. your macro file path)

If your are adding many excel workbooks and save it on different path and want 
to open this path so you should use below code.

Not  necessary to use event for this, you can simply write code after saving workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & Activeworkbook.Path, vbNormalFocus)
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to open the folder where the current workbook was saved automatically after saving. Paste this code in the ThisWorkbook code in the VB Editor

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Path, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the code, it is near working, but the output folder is wrong. it open my personal macro folder instead. not the the folder i saved the file to.

Comment: In the image above, the code is pasted in `ThisWorkbook` module of "Book1.xlsm". You have probably(99% sure) pasted it in the `ThisWorkbook` module of "Personal.xlsb"

Comment: i did paste on  ThisWorkbook module of "Personal.xlsb" but the folder not open after the save

Comment: you should paste the code in the excel file that you are saving. In my case it was Book1.xlsm.

Comment: Thanks for your help @nightcrawler23 . I managed to get it working now by using ''Activeworkbook.Path''